# Rigify Generate Rig: index out of range

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm using rigify to rig a character I've setup, the weight paint and movement all works fine but rigify is generating an error "Generation has thrown an exception: list index out of range" when I click generate rig. I've included a link to the blend file if that helps as I can't figure out whats causing the error and haven't been able to find an answer on Google. I've gone cleaned up my model and had a look through the bones but can't find any issues. I have changed some bones from the default rig if that's an issue so not sure if I need to do something extra to update rigify. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oVaTbJNIyH9ekEXSVOAklCkZe1uhcKSn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have deleted a bunch of bones that rigify can't work without. The problems are just everywhere, legs, spine, head. Any one of them could be throwing the exception.
I have two suggestions. If you want to learn how to use rigify correctly, I have a series of videos here:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJv68SSdwxip33M7snakl6Dx
But for the lego character, a custom rig may be better. Here is an AWESOME tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIaSCV9AUvI

Comment: Awesome thanks for the pointers that's really great help. I did watch a blender tutorial that did say you can remove them but I must have removed too many!